# How to match tab and newline but not space with REGEX?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match "tab" and "newline" meta chars but without "spaces" with REGEX in Java.

**\s** matches evrything i.e. tab, space and new line... But, I don't want "space" to be matched.

How do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out this http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/regular-expression/metacharacter-list.php

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One way to do it is:

```
[^\\S ]
```

The negated character class makes this regex to match anything except - `\\S` (non-whitespace) and `" "`(space) character. So, it will match `\\s` except space.

Answer (score 9):

Explicitly list them inside `[...]` (set of characters):

```
"[\\t\\n\\r\\f\\v]"
```