# How to protect PHP application from CRLF attack?

Tags: php, sanitize, crlf-vulnerability

I am using [Acunetix](http://www.acunetix.com) to scan my PHP application for security issues.
After all scans, I get a medium alert related to [CRLF vulnerability](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjIw7Csn-3NAhVJKpoKHTXTAkwQFgghMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.owasp.org%2Findex.php%2FCRLF_Injection&usg=AFQjCNHIFe_TJid5bsiKD83jOl-Iahgv0g&sig2=p0_MGQKN3JQ6MPVo0dvNQw). But I don't know how can I fix this issue.
I created a function to remove all possible codes for injections but it does not solve the problem.

```
function remove_crlf($input) {
    $output = str_replace(array('\r','\n','\r\n','\n\r','%0d','%0a'),null,$input);
    return $output;
}
```

Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

using regex:

```
$output = preg_replace("/[^\\S ]/", '', $input);
```

readed in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21620363/454827